# asp.net mvc4 code in div not appearing

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I started a new project, a mobile application, which already contains some example code.

The index page looks like this, when project is created (before I add my code to it):

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewBag.Message %></h2>

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
        <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") %></li>
        <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home") %></li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

Now, if I add the code shown below, it won't show. It will still show the code that is not in a div though (The code that was there from start).  Anyone can point out the error?

```
<div data-role="page" id="bodyPage" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"></div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text"  id="name" />
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" />
    <label>City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" />

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please, this is still an issue. If anyone knows, please share